# How to showPopupWindow after AsyncTask finished?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, popupwindow

I want to display a textView in popup Window when I click a View , but the calculation needs time, so I make the calculation in  AsyncTask, but how to show the  popup Window immediately after the  AsyncTask process is finished?

```
public void onClick(View widget) {

        MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(Object output) {
            meaning_result = (String) output;
            }
            });
         asyncTask.execute("xxxxx");
         showPopupWindow(widget);
}
```

This is my first thought but the `showPopupWindow(widget)` executes first and the  `meaning_result` has not assigned yet. How to make `showPopupWindow(widget)` runs once the meaning_result is assigned?

Comment: What is the code of MyAsyncTask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
public void showPopUp(final View widget){
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showPopupWindow(widget);
            }
        });
}
```

and :

```
public void onClick(final View widget) {

        MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(Object output) {
                meaning_result = (String) output;
                showPopUp(widget);
            }
        });
        asyncTask.execute("xxxxx");

    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your popup in the postExecute of your AsynTask.

```
public void onClick(View widget) {

     AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask(){

        @Override
        protected long doInBackground(){
            //Do your cacultation
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
             showPopupWindow(widget);
        }

        });
     asyncTask.execute("xxxxx");
}
```